# Cannot include Eigen and boost/regex at the same time

Tags: c++, regex, boost, eigen

I can include each library individually but as soon as I try to include them at the same time, I get a ton of errors. I'm using Boost v1_55_0 and Eigen v3.2.1.
Any idea what the problem might be?

My includes look like this:

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <Eigen>
```

I'm pasting the first couple of errors below, there are over 100 of them.

```
Error   1   error C1189: #error :  The Eigen/Array header does no longer exist in Eigen3. All that functionality has moved to Eigen/Core.   c:\local\eigen\array    8   1   Project1
2   IntelliSense: #error directive: The Eigen/Array header does no longer exist in Eigen3. All that functionality has moved to Eigen/Core.  c:\local\Eigen\Array    8   4   Project1
3   IntelliSense: expected a declaration    c:\local\boost_1_55_0\boost\functional\hash\extensions.hpp  160 13  Project1
4   IntelliSense: expected a declaration    c:\local\boost_1_55_0\boost\functional\hash\extensions.hpp  162 5   Project1
5   IntelliSense: expected a declaration    c:\local\boost_1_55_0\boost\functional\hash\extensions.hpp  377 1   Project1
6   IntelliSense: expected a declaration    c:\local\boost_1_55_0\boost\regex\v4\basic_regex.hpp    59  7   Project1
7   IntelliSense: expected a declaration    c:\local\boost_1_55_0\boost\regex\v4\basic_regex.hpp    100 7   Project1
8   IntelliSense: identifier "name" is undefined    c:\local\boost_1_55_0\boost\regex\v4\basic_regex.hpp    108 24  Project1
9   IntelliSense: explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)  c:\local\boost_1_55_0\boost\regex\v4\basic_regex.hpp    111 4   Project1
10  IntelliSense: a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function   c:\local\boost_1_55_0\boost\regex\v4\basic_regex.hpp    136 21  Project1
11  IntelliSense: a type qualifier is not allowed on a nonmember function   c:\local\boost_1_55_0\boost\regex\v4\basic_regex.hpp    146 33  Project1
12  IntelliSense: expected a declaration    c:\local\boost_1_55_0\boost\regex\v4\basic_regex.hpp    151 1   Project1
13  IntelliSense: expected a declaration    c:\local\boost_1_55_0\boost\regex\v4\basic_regex.hpp    153 1   Project1
```

Comment: I can't say specifically, but basically you've set up the project to have include directories for both boost regex and eigen and they have a file named the same thing, so it's getting confused. I think.

Comment: What do your includes look like?

Comment: I put them into the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boost is including the C++11 [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) header `array` but your include path is picking up the `Array` header (apparently obsolete) from Eigen. You must be on a file system that doesn't distinguish files by case.

It appears that the proper way to include an Eigen header is:

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
```

See for example the [Getting Started sample](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html). You should modify your include path to use the directory that contains the `Eigen/` header directory instead of putting the `Eigen/` directory on the include path.